# $X$ sends eigenvectors of $Y$ to eigenvectors of $Y$ - what can we say about $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ and $B$ are two finite dimensional normal operators, then, the following are equivalent:

- For all $v$ and $\lambda$ such that $Bv = \lambda v$, we have $B(Av) = \lambda(Av)$ ($A$ decomposes as a direct sum over the eigenspaces of $B$).
- $[A, B] = 0.$

I currently have two finite dimensional normal operators $C$ and $D$ which satisfy a generalized version of the first condition above: for all $v$ and $\lambda$ such that $Dv = \lambda v$, there exists $\gamma$ such that $D(Cv) = \gamma(Cv)$. In other words, $C$ sends eigenvectors of $D$ to eigenvectors of $D$, but the requirement that they remain in the same eigenspace is dropped.

My question is: are there any algebraic properties of $C$ and $D$ that are a consequence of this property, analogous to how $[A,B] = 0$?

Comment: Are you assuming finite-dimensional $C,D$?

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, thank you. Edited to make that clear.

Comment: Then you get something like $[D,C^{n!}]C^n=0$, $n$ the number of distinct eigenvalues of $D$, because while $C$ can move the eigenspaces, the image of $C^n$ will only consists of eigenspaces that $C$ actually comes back to in its eventual cycles, and $C^{n!}$ leaves those eigenspaces fixed.